# Visual Studio 2010 Problem with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2010, project

Today I opened an C++ Project, but I just receive the "Project Target Framework Not Installed" (Targeted framework:  .NETFramework,Version=v4.0)

At first my Project does not use any .NET Framework / CLR. (Win32 Console Application)
At second I have 4.0 installed.
At third in the Project XML File I does not found an TargetFramework Setting.

I reinstalled VS2010, I tried to (re)install .NET 4.0, Nothing -.-

Why VS2010 ask for .NET 4.0 in a Win32 Project ?

So I tried to open a older Project, but just the same.

Comment: Erm, what happened yesterday?

Comment: hehe,  I it is more then 1 day ago, I think 2 or 3 days. So I dont know what I done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my own Solution for my problem here is it, if someone have the same.

I just added:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

at

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
```

I don´t know why it don´t find 4.0 but 3.5. But no matter. Win32 without CLR dont need any .NET.

Comment: That's kind of strange. Somehow your .NET 4 framework was corrupted. Weird.

Comment: In Visual C# it works great. Other thing i have done to compile is set v9.00 to v10.00 (VS)